# JDK 8 old program throw exception --> handler class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring

Recently I got the new job and working on it. But recently I need to install JDK 1.8 on the running windows computer in which there is one scheduler job program, Then now It throws the exception as below. I do not know why?

```
12 Nov 2017 23:48:51,292 [DEBUG] (DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:128)  - Ignoring namespace handler [org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler]: handler class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:117)
    at ......................
    org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:382)
    at com.xxx.pci.util.ServiceLocator.getApplicationContext(ServiceLocator.java:24)
    at com.xxx.pci.decrypt.Decrypt.<init>(Decrypt.java:48)
    at com.xxx.mapper.SProductApplicationLogMapper.mapRow(SProductApplicationLogMapper.java:17)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:405)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:413)
    at com.xxx.AwipDataBean.getAllProductApplications(AwipDataBean.java:44)
    at 

public class ServiceLocator {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected ServiceLocator() {
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (applicationContext == null) {
            BeanFactoryLocator locator = ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("applicationContextDef.xml");
            BeanFactoryReference bfr = locator.useBeanFactory("applicationContext");
            BeanFactory factory = bfr.getFactory();
            applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) factory;
            //bfr.release();
        }
        return applicationContext;
    }

}
```

applicationContextDef.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <bean id="applicationContext"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>applicationContext.xml</value>
                <value>applicationContext-datasource.xml</value>
                <value>applicationContext-smtp.xml</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>mail.properties</value>
                <value>datasource.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

##datasource.properties

```
datasource.jndi.name=AWIP_DB
datasource.jndi.provider=t3://web-application04.xxxx.com:7101
```

[cannot change the spring version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtrVd.png)

Comment: please check if your spring context jar is inside classpath. Kindly also share your dependencies

Comment: I find spring version is 2.0. Is it a problem? Need to upgrade to spring 3.0?

Comment: I have uploaded the picture that said cannot change the spring version in myEclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Please add you configuration with classpath**.

My sample above show how to configure with applicationContext.xml.